# Adding Video links to an ebook

Tags: pdf, css

I am new to ebooks and am not really sure of the capabilities of the system. I have written a number of technical books which I was considering turning into video lectures. Now I think it would be much better to convert them to ebooks.

My question is: can I successfully add links to video content? I understand that it might be necessary to link to a webpage to reduce the file size of the ebook but I am concerned that it would look unprofessional if it is not a completely smooth transition. Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Video links or web links both are similar. They just refer to other locations and are opened by the default browser of the OS of the user. So is it just links to the content or you are interested in dynamic pdfs... Please also clarify which format of ebook you are considering each will have their way of updating the link details

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the process of writing a bi-lingual multi-column translation of an Adobe.pdf German book on some of the regional dialects in Germany.  I have successfully tested .pdf pages that have test links to German and English YouTube websites for video illustrations of my subject matter.

One English language YouTube website video I have successfully tested in a .pdf test file is a video demonstration of examples of German regional dialects.  Another video on the German YouTube is a longish (30 minutes) video about the post-WWII German "Kabineroller" small cars -- actually it is also a video 'travelogue' of sorts.

From my tests I can see that YouTube video links from within my text will work and will be highly useful -- when and if I can finish my Adobe .pdf eBook!

My tests were with *external video sources*, and for this reason my videos won't take up any space at all *within* my eBook.  Obviously though, with my method if you want to use explanatory videos in *your* eBook those videos will have to be posted and available separately on some sort of a support website, i.e., a public or private website.